# Why 'await' requires 'async' in function definition

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, dart

I'm currently learning Dart, but this is also applicable to what's going on in the JavaScript world right now, and it seems like C# also uses the same pattern.

In Dart, any function that uses `await` must itself be labeled asynchronous through `async` as follows:

```
import "dart:html";

main() async {
  var context = querySelector("canvas").context2D;
  var running = true;

  while (running) {
    var time = await window.animationFrame;
    ...
  }
}
```

This does not make sense to me. If a function is waiting on an asynchronous function to complete, is it not then considered blocking? Why do JS and Dart require it to be labeled asynchronous? Would it not be the opposite?

To me it would make far more sense if the calling function must use the `async` keyword if it calls any function that also includes it in its definition. In this pattern, `await` would be used to convert asynchronous functions to synchronous ones.

This way would also avoid duplicate functions, since right now, libraries seem to always have `func()` and `funcSync()` or `funcAsync()`.

Comment: AFAIK the difference between asynchronous and blocking is that you can have multiple asynchronous processes in a single thread (where one does work when the others do not), while a blocking processes block the entire thread.

Comment: `await would be used to convert asynchronous functions to synchronous ones` impossible to make an asynchronous function synchronous, if you think about it. Sure, in some cases, you can make a synchronous "version" of an asynchronous function, not simply though, would require completely different code, but you can't take an asynchronous function and "make it" synchronous. In javascript, `async/await` is syntactic sugar for Promises, which themselves are inherently asynchronous

Comment: Because `await` isn't blocking.  It's an asynchronous non-blocking wait.

Comment: @JaromandaX why would it be impossible? Is an asynchronous function not just a series of steps that just so happen to be executed away from the main thread? Why would you not be able to take those steps and put them back on the main thread?

Comment: I'm speaking from a javascript perspective, where `thread` is a meaningless concept :p

Comment: @juharr does using `await` not stop execution of the function? Why is that not considered blocking?

Comment: Related reading: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await/

Comment: in javascript, `await` does *pause* the function while waiting for the Promise it is `awaiting` to resolve. if the function called does not return a promise, then the result is converted to a promise - javascript behaviour is documented in [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) and [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) - this ability to be *paused* is only possible if the calling function is tagged async, so that it can return a Promise

Comment: @jeanluc Blocking means a thread is actively waiting.  Async lets the thread be used for something else while it waits.  That's why it isn't blocking.

Comment: The funny thing about this question is that taken literally, the actual answer (in C#) is simply that _"the `async` keyword is necessary, because `await` was introduced later in the development of the language, and there was the possibility that code might have had a user-defined identifier `await` in it; `async` allows code to opt-in, and prevents breaking existing code that's not async-aware. otherwise, the compiler would have just automatically made methods containing `await` into async methods, the way methods containing `yield` are automatically considerered iterator methods."

Comment: But it seems that's not really what you're asking anyway. You really just don't understand how `async`/`await` works, nor what the semantics are. You should read one of the many existing Q&A on the topic. We don't really need another rehash of it here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PeterDuniho please take a look at my edit

Comment: You would have preferred your question closed as "too broad" or "primarily opinion based" instead? Fact is, the marked duplicate addresses the questions you asked to the extent that C# is involved. If you didn't want a C#-centric answer, don't drag C# into the question at all. Stack Overflow isn't the place for a study in comparative language design, and the async features in each language aren't similar enough to discuss, never mind answer, your question without being excessively broad or simply a matter of opinion.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes I see. However, at the time of posting the question I did not know enough about the keywords and assumed naively that they meant the same thing across the three languages, as it seemed they were part of the same paradigm shift. Ironically the Dart await async seems to be more related to JS, and for whatever reason, I received no feedback from both those tags. Regardless, I removed the edit, and realized that tagging C# was not appropriate.

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate, and it isn't too broad or primarily opinion based either. [This](https://gist.github.com/Tiny-Giant/88e35bf8dc3a755db2e0ba6bbb29239c) Is how I would have answered this question.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a poor question. What are you asing--why your idea of what should work isn't done? The semantics are what they are. What does "would it not be the opposite?" mean? It *isnt* the opposite. Would--*if what?* We don't know your misconceptions and unless the designers happened to give a full analysis of their rationale we don't know why they chose what they did vs something else, *and* it doesn't matter. What matters is how things are defined and how you use them to get things done. Read your question & see what you actually wrote, rather than what you think you asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic semantics of `async`/`await` are the same across F#, VB, C#, Python, Dart, Hack, and JavaScript. So I think this question has sufficient answers from other languages. But since it has been reopened...

> If a function is waiting on an asynchronous function to complete, is it not then considered blocking?

No. Think about it this way:

- "asynchronous" means "does not block the calling thread".
- "synchronous" means "blocks the calling thread".

In an asynchronous method/function, the method/function can be *paused* at the `await` points, but it does not block the calling thread while it is paused. The function runs *serially* (one statement at a time), but *asynchronously* (without blocking the calling thread).

> To me it would make far more sense if the calling function must use the async keyword if it calls any function that also includes it in its definition.

That's how it already works... `await` consumes promise/future/task-returning methods/functions, and `async` marks a method/function as capable of using `await`.

> This way would also avoid duplicate functions

This is not possible with historically-blocking imperative languages. A method/function either blocks the calling thread until it is complete, or it does not. It is either synchronous or asynchronous.

There are some interesting alternative approaches to async methods/functions, though:

Go is not historically blocking; you can think of it as a language where every method/function is potentially asynchronous; doing this in any other runtime would be disastrous, but Go avoids those problems by implementing a strict goroutine system with message passing - no shared memory or threads allowed.

Another example are pure functional languages, where Future is just another monad and requires no special compiler support for `async`/`await` keywords.

Comment: If you do a million item array bubble sort in a for loop you're also blocking, essentially anything you do in javascript is blocking except when using Promises or timeouts.
And any blocking code you execute that doesn't use `await` needs not be asynchronous. That should be the decision of the developer.
You could even implement your own _await_ by doing a loop that breaks when the promise is completed, without needing the enclosing function to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

In Dart `async` indicates that the code containing `await` needs to be rewritten.
`async`/`await` is just syntactic sugar for the `Future.then()` base API, and the code is rewritten to this canonical `Future` based form, before it is compiled and executed.

Therefore `await` doesn't make code blocking.

There are also other supported markers like `*sync` and `*async` for generators.

See also 
- [Dart async/await internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907163/dart-async-await-internals)
- https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/await-async

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what your question has to do with C# but `await` is a most unfortunate keyword choice in C#. `await` is more understandable if you read it as `resume after` or even `yield then resume after`. When execution encounters `await`, it suspends the current function, returning to its caller. Once the `Task` being waited on is done, execution resumes after the `await` when the caller needs the result (from an `await` expression of its own).

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean they have the same meaning, though in this case it seems they do.

Answer (score -2):

This is a fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on "under-the-hood", I'm assuming the javascript async/await implementation mirrors (at least conceptually) that of the .NET world (which originated in F#).

Essentially:

1. A "unit of work" "token" of sorts (in C# a Task in JS a Promise) represents a completion of a task with an option of returning a value.
2. An "asynchronous" method is marked with async, to indicate to the compiler/interpreter/runtime whatever, that this method will return said token, and will likely consume some as well.
3. The thingamajig running it all, will (in C#'s case), rewrite the code on the sly to essentially do the following:

---

1. Start async method
2. Do standard normal code
3. Encounter "token" providing method
4. Call it, grab token
5. Setup a place the code can jump back to later
6. Is the token complete? If so, carry on, If not, set a **callback** to have the runtime come back to this place when it does

---

In this expanded context, the keywords make sense:

1. **async(hronous)** - A method that does some task that can take an indeterminate amount of time, that can be waited upon.
2. **await** - Indicates that instead of just grabbing the token from the async method and doing nothing with it, that you actually want to set up all this ceremony around listening out for when the work is done, and carrying on afterwards.

### **tl;dr**

Just think of async and await as **invisible callbacks**, async indicates when something can be listened out for, and await is what actually does the listening.