# Dart async/await internals

Tags: dart

I'm searching for the source of `async/await` implementations.

I would like to know how do they truly works in order to hack into `future.then()` to detect if there is code awaiting for execution or not.

**Edit**

This is what I'm willing to accomplish:

```
TrackingCompleter completer = new TrackingCompleter();
TrackingFuture future = completer.future;
print("isAwaited: ${future.isAwaited} (F)");
new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
  future.then((_) {
    print("executing sorping");
    print("isThenExecuted: ${future.thenExecuted} (F)");
    new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      print("isThenExecuted: ${future.thenExecuted} (T)");
      exit(1);
    });
  });
  print("isAwaited: ${future.isAwaited} (T)");
  print("isThenExecuted: ${future.thenExecuted} (F)");
  completer.complete();
});
```

As far, that's working. What I'd like to do now is to detect if `future.then` is called manually in the code or automatically with an `await` statement.

Comment: AFAIK async/await is part of the compiler. The code is rewritten on-the-fly to  `future.then()` and than executed only in this form. Perhaps you might investigate the event queue using Observatory https://dart-lang.github.io/observatory/ to get information about pending tasks

Answer (score 3):

The async/await implementation is based on futures.
Basically, `await` creates a function that contains the rest of the current function (the "continuation" of the await expression), and then calls `then` on the future you await with that function as argument.
There are more details needed to handle errors, but that's basically it.

In your case, if you want to know if `future.then` is called, I recommend just wrapping that particular future. Example:

```dart
import "package:async/async.dart";

class ThenWrapper<T> extends DelegatingFuture<T> {
  void Function(S Function(T), S Function(Object, StackTrace)) _callback;
  ThenWrapper(Future<T> future, this._callback): super(future);
  Future<S> then<S>(S onValue(T), {S onError(error, StackTrace st)}) {
    _callback(onValue, onError);
    return super.super(onValue, onError);
  }
}
...

TrackingFuture future = new ThenWrapper(completer.future, ...);
```

You can change the callback to do whatever you want.

Comment: I edited the question for adding details of my intentions